# React Router dom is not working when I hosted my React App with github pages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, react-router-dom, github-pages

import './App.css';

import NavBar from './component/NavBar.component';

import Main from './component/main.component';

import Footer from './component/foooter.component';

import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import About from './component/NavbarComponent/about.component';

import Hire from './component/NavbarComponent/hire.component';

import Support from './component/NavbarComponent/suport.component';

function App() {
return (

```
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Main />}/>

    <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />

    <Route exact path="/hire" element={<Hire/>} />

    <Route exact path="/support" element={<Support />} />

    <Route path="*" element={<h1>Page not Found</h1>} />

  </Routes>
  <Footer/>
</div>
```

);
}

export default App;

/*
Website link

https://iamniteshpandit.github.io/Chalo-deploy-karte-hain/

repository link:-

https://github.com/IAMNITESHPANDIT/Chalo-deploy-karte-hain

any suggestions you can  also do pull request  if that would be improve my code then I will definitely accept that :)

*/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71170324/deploy-react-app-with-json-server-as-backend/ try changing your path with the repo name as mentioned. for example `path="/"` becomes `path="/Chalo-deploy-karte-hain"`

Comment: See CRA docs for deploying to github pages, there's more to it than just simply setting a `homepage` value in your package.json file: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

Answer (score 0):

import './App.css';

import NavBar from './component/NavBar.component';

import Main from './component/main.component';

import Footer from './component/foooter.component';

import { Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";

import About from './component/NavbarComponent/about.component';

import Hire from './component/NavbarComponent/hire.component';

import Support from './component/NavbarComponent/suport.component';

function App() {
return (

```
  <Routes>
    /**here path changed path='/' into path="/Chalo-deploy-karte-hain" in-order to application would able to work with github pages  */
```

<Route exact path="/Chalo-deploy-karte-hain" element={}/>

```
    <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />

    <Route exact path="/hire" element={<Hire/>} />

    <Route exact path="/support" element={<Support />} />

    <Route path="*" element={<h1>Page not Found</h1>} />

  </Routes>

  <Footer/>

</div>
```

);
}

export default App;